# Is there a platform style for the white boxes on gray background common in Android apps?

Tags: android, default, styling

In a lot of applications I see white boxes/rectangles on a light gray brackground.
See:

- [Youtube app](https://lh6.ggpht.com/O4ncDa9FBG0YmXqO6SnKFU_2O9MhPt3tkR4d5RZ52ktgO-CfXxFtfHtMxbOOWHN8Yg=h900-rw)
- [Trigger](https://lh6.ggpht.com/XCgfZwLJDb75E3DsacXHEIGNMhMX0gtpejaICGEEFkqoyV_E1qZhxagsn1mxaeg-uaCk=h900-rw)
- [Trains timetable Italy](https://lh4.ggpht.com/rngO5wHn3fUNPyHkBJNzWCsgfjlekmo0MrHsS-2pIGEQdehPAv0NEvT3oBHa-6sam4pA=h310-rw)
- [Google Keep](https://lh5.ggpht.com/0hpHQxMmEDqf97zGqhJ_kLZA3msAxtiZ-nFci2nRv0blfZM3LZwpKpzhmGdTu8D__A=h900-rw)

Are those platform views, or styles I can apply to views? Or is it just a google style that other applications imitate? I'd like to have some elements like those in my app, but can't find anything on the internet.

Comment: This is no longer valid question because now we have design lib, support libs and etc. should be deleted

Answer (score 1):

As Viktor Yakunin mentioned, now it can be easily done with [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

In particular, staggered grid of Google Keep can be implemented as a [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` as `LayoutManager` and [`CardView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)s as view-elements.

Trains timetable Italy - two `CardView`s in horizonal `LinearLayout`, etc.

Google's tutorial about cards and recyclerviews is [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

(And back in 2013 - I believe, it's been done with some analogues of etsy\AndroidStaggeredGrid for staggered layouts and with lot's of pain with 9patch to make the shadows look correctly :-) )